# Custom Attribute Source Model for Multiselect

Tags: product-attribute, multiselect-attribute, source-model

I followed this tutorial here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-custom-attribute-source-type/

In this tutorial, there are two key settings which I want to change:

```
'type'              => 'int',    //backend_type
'input'             => 'select', //frontend_input
```

I tried using this:

```
'type'              => 'varchar',    //backend_type
'input'             => 'multiselect', //frontend_input
```

This works great from a UI standpoint, but I can't get Magento save any selection when I have the attribute setup this way.

How can I make a custom attribute source model that fully supports multiselect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this key:

```
'backend'=>'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array' //backend_model
```

to your attribute definition array

Comment: I came to the same conclusion right before falling asleep last night. So obvious. Thanks!